# Best way to avoid divide by zero while doing math on geometric shapes

Tags: geometry, coordinate-systems, divide-by-zero

I'm coding on a specialized motion controller hardware which uses a subset of Visual Basic language as its programming language. I need to make some calculations on given points, like getting center coordinates of an arc that is passing through 3 distinct points; shifting lines, getting intersection coordinates of 2 lines etc...

I'm using cartesian coordinate system for calculations. It seems that the code will get bloated while handling `divide by zero` cases.

So, what is the best coordinate system for such calculations? Or what is the best approach to keep such code small?

#### Example

The code giving center point coordinates of an arc that is passing through 3 points is as follows:

```
    ' p1: (px1, py1)  p2: (px2, py2) p3: (px3, py3)
    ' ----------------------------------------------

    m_r=(py2-py1)/(px2-px1) ' slope of the line between p1 and p2
    m_t=(py3-py2)/(px3-px2) ' slope of the line between p2 and p3

    center_x=(m_r*m_t*(py3-py1)+m_r*(px2+px3)-m_t*(px1+px2))/(2*(m_r-m_t))
    center_y=(-1/m_r)*(x_mrk-(px1+px2)/2)+(py1+py2)/2
```

As you can see, there are many cases that will cause a `divide by zero` exception. Should I use `if/else` structure or is there a better way?

Comment: does the framework support try/catch block? If so, use that

Comment: nope, it doesn't even have a support for defining functions (only `GOSUB` command can be used) (yes, really)

Comment: does it have something like OnError: goto line xxxx?

Comment: it has something like that, but the point is keeping the code clean and short as much as possible. If I use that structure, any exception will be handled by that routine, which will make the code spaghetti (anyway, I didn't get the point of using try/catch. what would be the difference between using try/catch and if/else blocks?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you calculate center point  of an arc that is passing through 3 points, you definitely need to check if these points lies on the same line. But rewrite expression

```
if (py2-py1)/(px2-px1) = (py3-py2)/(px3-px2)
```

to avoid dividing

```
Det = (py2-py1) * (px3-px2) - (py3-py2) * (px2-px1) 
if Det = 0 then ... `bad case
```

for else case (Det<>0) arc exists, and you can find center coordinates without zero-divide errors

```
center_x= ((py2-py1) * (py3-py2) * (py3-py1) + 
          (py2-py1) *(px2+px3) * (px3-px2) - 
          (py3-py2) * (px1+px2) * (px2-px1)) / (2 * Det)
```

Comment: yes, that's one of the possible error causes. I have to handle this case too but I faced with the `division-by-zero` problem when 2 of these points make a line with a slope of 90 degree (or 0 degree).

Comment: You don't need to calculate slopes at all. I rewrote the last expression without them (it is not thoroughly checked).

Comment: I didn't check your `center_x = ...` equation too but your suggested way is seems like the easiest (and clearer) way to go. Thanks.